# Spellcheck for Extjs textfields

Tags: extjs, spell-checking

I need spellcheck in an extjs textfield. A textarea doesn't work because I need it to only allow a user to enter a single line of input - no enter key. Any way to enable spellcheck for the textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get around the single line requirement and use a textarea, which by default uses spellcheck.  To force the textarea to be a single line add this to your textarea:

```
xtype: 'textarea',
grow: true,
growMax: 32,
enableKeyEvents: true,
listeneters: {
    keydown: 'disableNewLine'
}
```

And in your controller, add the function to disable the new line.

```
disableNewLine: function(textarea, e, eOpt) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.stopEvent();
    }
}
```

This prevents the user from adding a new line to their input just like a textfield would, but utilizes spellcheck. Also, 32 is the default height of a textfield, so it looks the exact same. Just setting the height doesn't work, the default seems to override that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it after the component is rendered.
Also make sure the browser you are using supports spell check.
http://caniuse.com/#search=spellcheck

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(cmp) {
            cmp.getEl().set({
                "spellcheck": 'true'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

see [api](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-inputAttrTpl)

`inputAttrTpl: 'autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"'`

It works fine under safari!

Answer (score 1):

This override worked fine for me with ExtJS6 & Chrome:

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.form.field.Text',{
    override: 'Ext.form.field.Base',
    /**
     * Ensure all text fields have spell check disabled
     */
    inputAttrTpl: [
        'spellcheck=false'
    ],
    constructor: function () {          

        this.callParent(arguments); 

    }
});
```

Comment: Nice ExtJS 6 solution